# How to pass and read the vlaues from map in Drools DRT template?

Tags: drools, drools-fusion, drools-flow

I am trying to pass a map in DRT template of the of the drools like this

**TEMPLATE**

```
template "another map"
rule "test map_2"
no-loop true
dialect "java"
when
         namedmap:Map(map:"${namedTags}")
         review:FactNew(
         (compareNamedTags(namedmap,namedTags))
         )
then
System.out.println("Value is present in the list: "+ namedmap.get("objective"));
modify(review){setComment("accepted")}
end
end template
```

**DRL GENERATED**

```
rule "test map_2"
no-loop true
dialect "java"
when
         namedmap:Map(map:"{key1=value1, key2=value2}")
         review:FactNew(
         (compareNamedTags(namedmap,namedTags))
         )
then
System.out.println("Value is present in the list: "+ namedmap.get("key2"));
modify(review){setComment("accepted")}
end
```

**FUNCTION TO CHECK THE MAP**

```
function Boolean compareNamedTags(Map namedTagsMap, Map namedTags){
    System.out.println("Comparing the named Tags map");
    System.out.println("namedTag -->"+namedTagsMap );
    System.out.println("namedTagsMap -->"+namedTags );
    System.out.println("equality -->"+namedTagsMap.keySet().equals(namedTags.keySet()) );
    boolean flag = false;
    flag = namedTagsMap.equals(namedTags);
    return true;
}
```

While firing the rule there is no error but no output is printed. Also there is no call to the function why? Is this the right to pass the map  in DRT and use it in the when condition of the rule.

Please provide some guidance on how one can pass a map in the DRT template and use it.

Comment: This logic works when I insert a map in the working memory. Why?

Comment: and it picks the same map for both, the map that is passed in the working memory.